# Deserialize derived type when base class is passed in as param

Tags: c#

I have a set of methods to serialize/deserialize my custom Message class.

This works fine for `Message` but not for derived classes like `TestMessage` since the deserializer obviously has no idea about the data and returns only what we tell it to.

```
public class Message 
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
}

public class TestMessage : Message
{
    public string OtherString {get; set; }
}

public byte[] SerializeMessage(Message message)
{
    using (MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream())
    {
        new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(fs, message);
        return fs.ToArray();
    }
}
public Message DeserializeMessage(byte[] data)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        return new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(ms) as Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Sorry, code updated

Comment: If this is part of the same project as your previous question about async TCP communication, I highly recomment **not** using the BinaryFormatter. You can find this warning in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization): *"Binary serialization can be dangerous. Never deserialize data from an untrusted source and never round-trip serialized data to systems not under your control."*

Comment: As for the actual question. As far as I know, the BinaryFormatter should know which type was serialized (I think the type name is even included in the serialized data). Your deserialization method should already return a `TestMessage`, you just need to check if it is one, e.g. with `if(message is TestMessage)`.

Comment: Do you know, from the caller side, if it is a `Message` or derived `Message`?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Thanks for that article. Wasn't aware but I guess it should be pretty obvious the security risks for it. It'll only be used in a closed environment but good knowledge to have.

Comment: Are the serialization methods part of the `Message` class?

Comment: @JuanR [No](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer You are correct again. My problem was actually due to not marking my class as Serializable, I just didn't see the correct exception because of problems with my async exception handling. If you'd like to make an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thank you again

Comment: @user3953989 This would be a good opportunity for a self-answer, which is perfectly acceptable on StackOverflow. Just make sure to include all details that lead you to find that mistake so it might be helpful for other users too. Feel free to @ me when you do so I can upvote it.

Comment: @user3953989: For future reference, if you encounter an exception, please note that in your post and provide the exception stack if possible so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was actually because I did not add `[Serializable]` to my `TestMessage` class. I was not seeing the exception because I was doing this work in an `async void` method which the caller can't catch the exception.

As @Manfred Radlwimmer and @JuanR pointed out deserialization will happen correctly as is.

Answer (score 1):

The serialized version contains information about the type. When you deserialize the byte array, the object will be of the original type.

You can verify this by debugging your code.

You should be able to cast it back to the original type once you get the result of the call to `DeserializeMessage`, provided you know what it is.

Alternatively, you can modify your method to use generics:

```
public T DeserializeMessage<T>(byte[] data) where T:Message
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        return (T)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
var message = DeserializeMessage<TestMessage>(bytes);
```

Comment: This is completely wrong and misleading. (The last sentence anyways)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer: I can rephrase it a little but if you are going to criticize the answer, please be kind enough to explain your rationale.

Comment: I will augment with a sample to illustrate.

Comment: All messages are going to be types derived of `Message` so the `as Message` is the sensible thing to do. Changing the return type to object will not be helpful in any way and does not solve *any* problems. The only thing missing (as I've already mentioned in the comments) is a check what kind of message it actually is.

Comment: What bothers me most about your explanation is the last sentence *"Return type object from your method to get the actual type back."* which is completely false.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer: Thank you. I rephrased my answer as it was indeed misleading.

Comment: Still not really a full answer, but at least it's not wrong anymore (downvote removed)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer: I added some more stuff, including an alternative using generics. Thanks for removing the downvote.